# Google sheets indirect formula dynamic range building

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an INDIRECT formula in my google sheet.

Formula: `=INDIRECT("B"&J4)`  --> this works without any issues.

I am however trying to define a range with it.

I am trying to get this result: **B5:B**  --> Number 5 would be dynamically pulled from J4.

I tried entering  `=INDIRECT("B"&J4):B` but that is giving me an error: 'Unknown range name: 'B'.'
If however I enter `=INDIRECT("B"&J4):B10` for example, the formula will work and will pull the data correctly but I really need the range to be defined B5:B (five being dynamically pulled as described above).

I am hoping to use the here described indirect formula in COUNTIFS formula  in order to dynamically define COUNTIFS range, for reference:

```
=IF(MONTH(B4:B)=8,COUNTIFS(B4:B,">="&B4, B4:B,"<="&EOMONTH(B4,0)),)
```

=IF(MONTH(B4:B)=8,COUNTIFS(**INDIRECT("B"&J4):B**,">="&B4, B4:B,"<="&EOMONTH(B4,0)),)

but it is not working. Not sure if this a syntax error of if INDIRECT cannot be used to define a range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the whole range as text inside the INDIRECT Function.

```
=INDIRECT("B"&J4&":B")
```