# Can an open-ended range column be made dynamic with a Google Sheets Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula in `E4`to return the lengths of cells in the given array `K4:M`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(K4:M)>0,LEN(K4:M),""))
```

Is it possible to make the `M` range's end of the given array `K4:M` 'dynamic' and based on this condition:

If I have range `K3:O3` the folowwing values:

```
3   7   4   0   0
```

retrieved with those formulas in `K3:O3`:

```
=counta(K4:K) =counta(L4:L) =counta(M4:M) =counta(N4:N) =counta(O4:O)
```

Screenshots:

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

How can the `M` be selected and used as the `K4:M` range end column based on the value in `M3` being the last in the range `K3:3` being greater than zero? If possible with a google sheets formula?

In pseudocode it would amount to:

`K4:The Last Column Letter With value > 0 in range K3:3` = `K4:M`

I need it to be dynamic because the input in `K4:variableend` will vary.

In the given example I put the output cell in `E4` on the same sheet for ease of presentation of the problem but in real implementation it will be on another sheet to avoid conflict with range `K4:variableend`.

I tried using the `ADDRESS` function to retrieve the `M` column letter and `INDIRECT` function to use as reference for the range end in `K4:M` but was not making progresses.

And I'm not sure how to formulate the "last column greater than zero based on the values from range `K3:3` " part.

```
=Substitute(Address(1,13,4),"1","")
```

and

```
=INDIRECT(E1)
```

I looked for another related question but could only find this one which I could not apply successfully to my case:

[Google sheets indirect formula dynamic range building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545039/google-sheets-indirect-formula-dynamic-range-building)

[image: 3rd]

[image: 4th]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you try:*

```js
=indirect("K4:"&substitute(address(1,max(filter(column(K3:3),K3:3>0)),4),1,))
```

***OR***

```js
=let(Σ,K4,
     Σ:offset(Σ,9^9,index(match(,0/(K3:3<>0)))-1))
```

Comment: Amazing again! Both work as expected. Will need to study it in details next. Thanks again. Be well!

Comment: @rockingfreakshow. I tried to apply it to get the lengths of cells but did not succeed. For example with this version of the zour 2nd formula: `=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(let(Σ,K4,Σ:offset(Σ,9^9,index(match(,0/(K3:3<>0)))-1)))>0,LEN(let(Σ,K4,Σ:offset(Σ,9^9,index(match(,0/(K3:3<>0)))-1))),""))`  Or I also tried this `=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN("K4:"&let(Σ,K4,Σ:offset(Σ,9^9,index(match(,0/(K3:3<>0)))-1)))>0,LEN("K4:"&let(Σ,K4,Σ:offset(Σ,9^9,index(match(,0/(K3:3<>0)))-1))),""))` . How to get it to return the lenghts of range `K4:M11` or up to the last column from `K3:3 > 0`?

Comment: I also tried with your 1st formula but it returned all the blank columns for `K3:3 > 0`. If also possible, how to return the same lengths of the cells from range `K4:M11` with the 1st formula? I tied this without success: `=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(indirect("K4:"&substitute(address(1,max(filter(column(K3:3),K3:3>0)),4),1,)))>0,LEN(indirect("K4:"&substitute(address(1,max(filter(column(K3:3),K3:3>0)),4),1,))),""))` but it returns the extra columns. Thanks!

Comment: Please share a test sheet recreating this scenario of yours & ***manually enter*** the expected output so that I'd have a clear picture to work it out.

Comment: @rockingfreakshow please ignore my comments. It works great for these as well. I had the wrong input row as this (and did not catch the mistake in my big dataset, but it got obvious upon recreating it on small sample test): The error: https://i.imgur.com/5KAmAMt.png The fix: https://i.imgur.com/W5yvuZI.png Please forgive the disturbance. I'll do the sample test before on my next issues going forward! Thanks again.